# Is a function of a function the same as a two-argument function?

Tags: functions

Say I have a function $g$ described by $$(x\stackrel f\mapsto y)\stackrel g\mapsto z$$  That is, $g$ takes a function, $f$, and maps it to another object, maybe just a real number or vector or whatever, $z$.  How does this relate to the function $$(x,y)\stackrel h\mapsto z$$  Are they, in effect, the same?

P.S. I don't know what tags to choose for this, so feel free to edit.

Comment: No. However, a function $x\mapsto(y\mapsto z)$ *is* the same as a function $(x,y)\mapsto z$, see [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not the same. You are confusing two related, but ultimately different function types.

One kind of function is

```
f : (a -> b) -> c
```

And the other kind is

```
g : a -> (b -> c)
g' : (a, b) -> c
```

One can construct an isomorphism between `g` and `g'` and it's easy to see how.

Given a `g`, I can construct a `g'` list so:

```
g'(a, b) = g(a)(b)
```

And to construct `g` from `g'`, one can do this:

```
h_a(b) = g(a, b)
g(a) = h_a
```

Where `h_a` is some function `h` indexed by `a`. You can think of `h` "having access" to `a`.

This isomorphism is called as [currying / partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) and comes up often in functional programming languages.

These rules are often implicit in [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), a branch of mathematics created to study functions and their construction (and the relationship of these to Turing machines).

Answer (score 3):

Your idea has a name: [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

There is an equivalence between functions
$$f:X\times Y\longrightarrow Z$$
and
$$\text{curry}(f):X\longrightarrow Z^Y$$
defined by
$$(\text{curry}(f)(x))(y) = f(x,y).$$

Comment: Yes, except that the OP asked about $(x\mapsto y)\mapsto z$, which is of type $Y^X\to Z$.